# Change value of databound control within Repeaters in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a nested repeater control that displays a list of data, in my case it is an FAQ list. here is the design portion:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="lists" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h2 class="sf_listTitle"><asp:Literal ID="listTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal></h2>

        <p class="sf_controlListItems">
            <a id="expandAll" runat="server">
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:ExpandAll %>"></asp:Literal>
            </a>
            <a id="collapseAll" runat="server" style="display:none;">
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:CollapseAll %>"></asp:Literal>
            </a>
        </p>

        <ul class="sf_expandableList" id="expandableList" runat="server">
            <asp:Repeater ID="listItems" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <h1 id="headlineContainer" runat="server" class="sf_listItemTitle">
                            <a id="headline" runat="server" title="<%$Resources:ClickToExpand %>"></a>
                        </h1>
                        <div id="contentContainer" runat="server" class="sf_listItemBody" style="display:none;">
                            <asp:Literal ID="content" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The repeater that I am interested in is the second repeater, `listItems`. In my code-behind, I cannot directly call `listItems` and see the controls inside of it. I tried to grab the control inside of `list.DataBinding` (maybe I need to use a different event?) method:

```
void lists_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var oRepeater = (Repeater) lists.FindControl("listItems");
}
```

but this comes up as `null`. Can anyone give me some pointers/tips of what I need to do to gain access to the `listItems` repeater and it's children controls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lists
```

belongs to each RepeaterItem, not directly to the Repeater itself.

Try :-

```
void lists_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{


    if ( e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem 
        || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item )
    {
       Repeater oRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("listItems");

       // And to get the stuff inside.
       foreach ( RepeaterItem myItem in oRepeater.Items )
       {
          if ( myItem.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem 
              || myItem.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item )  
          {
             Literal myContent = (Literal)myItem.FindControl("content");

             // Do Something Good!
             myContent.Text = "Huzzah!";

          }
       }
    }
}
```

And you should be good :)

Edited to incorporate DavidP's helpful refinement.

Comment: No probs.  The ASP .NET controls hierarchy is lovely once you get to know it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change that line to

```
var oRepeater = (Repeater) e.Item.FindControl("listItems");
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I completely forgot haha. So once I get this oRepeater, how do I get the control literal?

Comment: Think I've got you covered in my response now, sir :)

Comment: Anders you can add the attribute OnItemDataBinding="listItems_ItemDataBound" to the listItems repeater tag. You don't need to iterate through all it's items.

Answer (score 0):

You're close!  Inside your event handler check the RepeaterItemEventArgs for what kind of row you're dealing with.  Your child repeater will only be available on (Alt)Item rows, not headers or footers.  My guess is that it's blowing up on the header.